# Is it possible for continuous fourier transform of a function to have values only on finite number of frequencies?

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

Is it possible for continuous fourier transform of a function to have values only on finite number of frequencies? Or do these values necessarily impulse values, not complex numbers?

Comment: Think about parseval's theorem (energy in time = energy in frequency). Note that if it were non-zero only at a finite number of points and finite at all those points, it would have zero energy.

Comment: This depends a bit what you mean by "continuous Fourier transform" and "function". For $f \in L^1 + L^2$, then $\widehat{f}$ is a "function" (an element of $L^\infty + L^2$) and if $\widehat{f} = 0$ holds a.e., then $\widehat{f} = 0$ as a tempered distribution, and thus $f=0$ (a.e.). But for example if $f \equiv 1$, then $\widehat{f} = \delta_0$ is "zero everywhere but at the origin", but $\widehat{f}$ is not a function anymore...

Comment: What happens if signal has values on discretely (in other words, not continuous) infinite number of frequencies? I have a hard time picturing calculus here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose $g$ is the Fourier transform of some $f$, and that $g$ is zero everywhere except a finite set $\{x_n\}$, where it is finite. Then $g$ is a function (i.e. "not a distribution"*) that is zero a.e.; what happens if you integrate a function that is zero a.e.?

In particular, what if you take the inverse Fourier transform of $g$?

*: of course, functions are distributions, but hopefully my meaning is understood and you will allow me to be informal here.